# Selenium - click on anchor link without class within a div with a classname

Tags: python, selenium

I have a url that I want to scrape data from. I am using selenium to open the site. I want to access the page within the `heading` class and take information from this page. I am unsure of how to click a link within a div if it doesn't have a classname. It is giving me the following error message:

> Unable to locate element a

the **html** looks like the following

```
<div class="heading">
    <a href="....">Text here</a>
</div>

<div class="heading">
    <a href="....">Text here</a>
</div>
```

**PYTHON**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

 def init_driver():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
    return driver


def lookup(driver, query):
    driver.get("http://www.sportbirmingham.org/directory?sport=&radius=15&postcode=B16+8QG&submit=Search")
    try:
        parentElement = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("heading")
        print parentElement
        elementList = parentElement.find_element_by_tag_name("a")
        print elementList
    except TimeoutException:
        print("not found")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = init_driver()
    lookup(driver, "Selenium")
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Do you have it's id?

Comment: @omri_saadon it doesn't have one, just a classname

Comment: So what's wrong with your `CSS` selector `.heading a`? Do you get exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you're trying to call `parentElement.find_element_by_tag_name('a')` while `parentElement` is a list, so you cannot apply `find_element_by_tag_name()` method. Try below code:

*Python 3.6*

```
def lookup(driver, query):
    driver.get("http://www.sportbirmingham.org/directory?sport=&radius=15&postcode=B16+8QG&submit=Search")
    try:
        [print(link.text) for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//h2[@class="heading"]/a')]
    except TimeoutException:
        print("not found")
```

*Python 2.7*

```
def lookup(driver, query):
    driver.get("http://www.sportbirmingham.org/directory?sport=&radius=15&postcode=B16+8QG&submit=Search")
    try:
        for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//h2[@class="heading"]/a'):
            print link.text
    except TimeoutException:
        print "not found"
```

If you want to click exact link you can use:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Sport Birmingham').click()
```

Comment: ```[print(link.text) for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//h2[@class="heading"]/a')]
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```

Comment: Hmm...do you use `Python 2.x`?

Comment: `Python 2.7.13`

Comment: last question, can you see there is an email address if you click on each of the links. Is it possible to get this after each link clicked?

Comment: Try this `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="widget-contact"]//a').get_attribute('href')`

Comment: I have asked a follow up question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186921/python-find-email-address-on-page-with-selenium . you can prob get more points :-)

Answer (score 0):

You want to get to the inner tag that under the `heading` class, you should replace the space with `>`

Change this:

```
button = driver.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.css, ".heading a")))
```

To:

```
button = driver.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.css, ".heading>a")))
```

Comment: By.css wasn't working so have updated the question slightly.

Comment: This haven't worked? `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.heading>a')`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to find an `a` tag element inside the first element that contains the class `heading`. You need after this line:

```
parentElement = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("heading")
```

To loop over the results (which is parentElement**s**) and get the `a` tag under it, then get it's text. From looking at your URL, the first `heading` div doesn't have an `a` under it, hence the error.

EDIT: looping over the elements (Warning: I know little python)

```
for a_element in parentElements:
    if (a_element.find_elements_by_tag_name('a').count > 0)
        a_text = a_element.find_element_by_tag_name('a').text
```

Comment: i think some of your answer is missing. If there is no a tag underneath the first heading how can i ignore this?