# python - Find email address on page with selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I am trying to get a list of email addresses from a website and am very close. The code I have can be seen below. I am getting the following error.

What happens is that there is a page of links which are then clicked on and in the following page there is an email address.

I am trying to print out the email address inside each of the pages after the link is clicked.

[Here is an example of a page that the link clicks through to](http://www.sportbirmingham.org/directory/sport-birmingham).

> xTraceback (most recent call last):   File "scrape.py", line 34, in
>   
>       lookup(driver)   File "scrape.py", line 26, in lookup
>       emailAdress = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="widget-contact"]//a‌​').get_attribute('hr‌​ef')
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 293, in find_element_by_xpath
>       return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 752, in find_element
>       'value': value})['value']   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 236, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
>   line 192, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException:

I am using `python 2.7.13`.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from lxml import html
import requests
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

def init_driver():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
    return driver


def lookup(driver):
    driver.get("http://www.sportbirmingham.org/directory?sport=&radius=15&postcode=B16+8QG&submit=Search")
    try:
        for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//h2[@class="heading"]/a'):
            link.click()
            emailAdress = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="widget-contact"]//a‌​').get_attribute('hr‌​ef')
            print emailAdress
    except TimeoutException:
        print "not found"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = init_driver()
    lookup(driver)
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.quit()
```

When I try and continue to the next page of links I get the following error

> File "scrape.py", line 43, in 
>       lookup(driver)   File "scrape.py", line 26, in lookup
>       links.extend([link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//h2[@class="heading"]/a')])   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py",
>   line 139, in get_attribute
>       self, name)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 465, in execute_script
>       'args': converted_args})['value']   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 236, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
>   line 192, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message:
>   The element reference is stale. Either the element is no longer
>   attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed.

Comment: Could you post some html so we can verify if selector is right?

Comment: Share full exception log

Comment: @Andersson full log shared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seem to be copy/paste issue. Sometimes when you copy code from StackOverflow answers, some hidden characters might be present. Your `XPath` in `Python` shell appears like `'//div[@id="widget-contact"]//a‌​??'`. You should re-write it manually to get rid of those `??`...

Also note that your code will not work as you stuck on the first iteration- there is no turning back to search page.

Try to use below code instead:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

def lookup(driver):
    driver.get("http://www.sportbirmingham.org/directory?sport=&radius=15&postcode=B16+8QG&submit=Search")
    links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//h2[@class="heading"]/a')]
    page_counter = 1
    while True:
        try:
            page_counter += 1
            driver.find_element_by_link_text(str(page_counter)).click()
            links.extend([link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//h2[@class="heading"]/a')])
        except NoSuchElementException:
            break            
    try:
        for link in links:
            driver.get(link)
            try:
                emailAdress = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="widget-contact"]//a').text
                print emailAdress
            except NoSuchElementException:
                print "No email specified"
    except TimeoutException:
        print "not found"
```

Comment: it gets the first one, but then crashes when it gets to the next page.. this is the error message ```raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //div[@id="widget-contact"]//a```

Comment: because you try to find another contact on the same page. You should perform driver.navigate().back()

Comment: This is because on some pages there is no emails. code updated

Comment: @Andersson thanks very much! the very last thing. can you see that there are numerous pages, how can you click on next link after it goes through the first page?

Comment: @Andersson i am getting the following error - `selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference is stale. Either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed.`

Comment: On which line ?

Comment: @Andersson see updated answer --- error was too long for a comment

Comment: Works perfect for me... Try to add `time.sleep(0.5)` right after `driver.find_element_by_link_text(str(page_counter)).click()`

Answer (score 1):

You just need more precise X-PATH (aslo with calling *text* method):

```
emailAdress = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="body"]/dl/dd[2]').text
```

But this example works with Python3. Let me know if it works for you.
I would also recommend to use "XPath Helper" extension for Chrome.

Comment: do u know how to do it with python 2?